# Shell script not seeing files DEBIAN

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian, vps

I am using a shell script on My Debian 7 VPS, and it calls for 2 files to be in the Server Directory, (java.pid and screen.name).  So I created them, and they have no text in them.  I then get a error saying:

```
vanilla.sh: line 85:  Vanilla-Server-Files/java.pid: No such file or directory
vanilla.sh: line 86:  Vanilla-Server-Files/screen.name: No such file or directory
```

Both files have full file permissions, so any fix would be helpful.

Thanks
- Thomas

The script can be found here:

http://pastebin.com/kynbWzyW

Comment: When you debug this, what's the value of `$MCPATH` right before those lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of in this script:

```
MCPATH="/home/$USERNAME/minecraft"
```

but you place your files into directory:

```
Vanilla-Server-Files
```

check this, create ~/minecraft and put files into it

Comment: sorry I didn't metion it, but I changed that part of the code :P

Comment: Put your current code and full directory path to your files in pastebin, because of I can't help you, if you show me not your script.

Comment: MCPATH="Vanilla-Server-Files" - bad idea, because of bash try to find this path in directory, where the script was called. Use full path instead, or call your script only from the folder, contains your Vanilla-Server-Files directory.